# Create PKGBUILD from .deb

Tags: arch-linux, packaging, deb

I have a `.deb` debian package which essentially contains the binaries of the software as a `/usr/share/bin` folder in a compressed `data` file, and another metadata compressed file containing the checksums of the other files.

My goal is to create a `PKGBUILD` to install such .deb package correctly on archlinux.

What's the proper way to do that?

Is enough to copy the contents of that `/usr/share/bin` directory into the `pkg` `/usr/share/bin` fakeroot environment using the `build()` function? The folder will be copied to the true `/usr/share/bin` location when the builded package is actually installed?

Comment: Essentially, yes (except use the package function). Look in the AUR for other packages ending with `-bin` and use the same approach...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it will work in the same way as other PKGBUILDs with binary sources - extract it and copy files. The only thing which should be mentioned is that deb-archive consists of 3 other files - `debian-binary`, `control.tar.gz`, `data.tar.gz`. makepkg will extract only first-level archive and then you should manually extract `data.tar.gz`.

```
prepare() {
    tar -zxvf data.tar.gz
    #tar -xvf data.tar.xz    # if archives are .tar.xz instead of .tar.gz
}

package() {
    # copy files
}
```

Alternatively, you can place deb-archive in noextract array and then manually extract only `data.tar.gz`:

```
$ ar p source.deb data.tar.gz | tar zx
```

Comment: `makepkg` changes the current directory to `$srcdir` before executing functions, so you don't need to include that anymore...

Comment: @jasonwryan, several developers have stated that there's no guarantee that such will remain true. For longevity's sake, it may make sense to leave the customary `cd "${srcdir}"` line in place.

Comment: @HalosGhost I'd not heard that. By the same logic, there is no guarantee that it will become false... :)