# Archlinux proper PKGBUILD: Python executable error

Tags: arch-linux, python, makepkg

In a [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152368/create-pkgbuild-from-deb), I asked about how to write a `PKGBUILD` to install a binary `.deb` package. The solution was to extract the contents of the `.deb` and copy the data to the archlinux package fakeroot, `"${pkgdir}/"`.

That means if the `.deb` contains a `data.tar.gz` with the binaries stored in a `usr/lib` directory, the process to install this package is (In the `PKGBUILD`):

```
package()
{
    cd $srcdir

    tar -xvzf data.tar.gz

    install -dm755 "${pkgdir}/usr/lib"
    cp -r -f "${srcdir}/usr/lib" "${pkgdir}/"
}
```

However if I do that the package is installed successfully, but I cannot open the binaries (Written in python). If I execute a binary installed in that way, returns this error:

> Cannot open self [path to executable] or file [path to executable].pkg

On the other hand, if I write the `PKGBUILD` in the wrong way, that is, copying the binaries directly to the system root during `package()`:

```
cp -r -f "${srcdir}/usr/lib "/"
```

The programs work perfectly.

**Is there something I'm missing?**

[Here](https://github.com/Manu343726/biicode-aur) is the package.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2357

In your case, it is maybe due to stripping the binary (see that "prelink" ticket linked from there). Likely fixed in pyinstaller 3.2.1 soon.